# Download a Google Document as a PDF with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, pdf, google-docs

I am attempting to create a Google Sheet where a user can enter in several (6) numerical values as function parameters and click a button to download content generated by the function and the user parameters as a PDF. Currently, I have got the script to write the data to a Google Doc with the correct formatting. How can I have the document downloaded as a PDF by the button press?

Here is my code so far:

`Code.gs`

```
/**
 * Create a data based off of user specified inputs from Google Sheets
 */
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var userParams = [];

  for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    userParams.push(data[i][1]);
  }

  var problems = genData(
    userParams[0],
    userParams[1],
    userParams[2],
    userParams[3],
    userParams[4],
    userParams[5]
  );

  var document = DocumentApp.create(`Problems: ${
    userParams.toString().replace(/,/g, ", ")
  }`);

  var documentId = document.getId();
  var documentUrl = `https://docs.google.com/document/d/${documentId}/edit`;
  var body = document.getBody();

  var FontStyle = {};
  FontStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = "Courier";
  FontStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 24;
  body.setAttributes(FontStyle);
  
  for(var i = 0; i < problems.length; i++) {
    body.appendParagraph(problems[i].replace(/,/g, ", ") + "\n");
  }

  openUrl(documentUrl);
}


function genData(param1, param2, param3, param4, param 5, param6) {
  /* Implemented in a separate file */
}

function openUrl( url ){
  /* Implemented in a separate file */
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) functionality.

More specifically, you can use the [getFileById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid) in conjunction with the [getAs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getAs(String)) functionality to get the document as a PDF. Something like...

```
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).getAs('application/pdf');
```

Since this returns a blob you can create a new file using the blob with something like

```
var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdf);
```

Finally you can use the [getDownloadUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdownloadurl) method to get the download URL of the new pdf file and redirect to there or download in some other way.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added the following lines to the end of `myFunction`:

```
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).getAs('application/pdf');

  var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdf);

  openUrl(pdfFile.getDownloadUrl());
```
but now the only issue is that the downloaded PDF is empty and does not contain any of the content as the Google Doc. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: It's hard to say without all the details, but there a few things you can try. While debugging, make sure the "var pdf" actually contains a blob of content. If not, you know the getFileById or getAs is failing.

You can do the same with the "pdfFile" and make sure it's actually creating the file properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- On Google Spreadsheet, you want to create a new Document and put the texts to the document, and you want to download it as a PDF file.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this case, please modify `myFunction()` as follows.

#### From:

```
openUrl(documentUrl);
```

#### To:

```
document.saveAndClose();
var convetedToPdf = `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=pdf&id=${documentId}`;
var html = `<script>window.open('${convetedToPdf}', '_blank'); google.script.host.close();</script>`;
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "sample");
```

- In this modification, `openUrl(documentUrl)` is not used.
- When this modified script is run, a PDF file is downloaded by opening a dialog on Spreadsheet.
- `document.saveAndClose()` saves the document. By this, when the document is converted to a PDF format, the PDF data has the values.
- `convetedToPdf` is the endpoint for converting from a document to a PDF format. This endpoint can be retrieved by Drive API. But, when the file ID is known, this endpoint can be created using the file ID.
- `showModalDialog` opens a dialog on Spreadsheet. By a dialog, Javascript is run, and download the PDF file.

#### References:

- [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveAndClose())
- [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html)